# How will you refactor the following code?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

```
while(!isRunning){
    now = getSystemTime();
    deltaTime = now - lastTime;
    lastTime = now;
    if(deltaTime >= 1000){
        //do something      
     }
}
```

This piece of code looks awkward to me. I want the thread to "do something" every 1000 units of time, but the while loop will run infinitely before 1000 units of time passes, which wastes resoure of CPU. How do you think I could refactor this piece of pseudo code? Notice that it may be true that "do something" may take more than 1000 units of time.
PS:
I am coding using java and want a solution to the problem with Java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off-topic for SO. It *may* be on-topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but check their faq.

Comment: This would not be on-topic for Code Review, as it looks like example code.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't think you are asking the right question.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but you could take a look at `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Java [scheduled executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). There is a method called scheduleAtFixedRate you can use. There is a class called TimeUnit which is used in this method to make things run at certain periods. Disadvantage to this is you have to create a instanve of Callable or Runnable which is a bit clunky in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the code is performing a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), meaning, wasting CPU cycles until `delta` is bigger than 1 second.

It would be better to simply sleep for a second instead, and allow other processes to take advantage of the CPU cycles while your process is doing nothing:

```
while(!isRunning){
    doSomething();
    sleep(1000); // see implementation below
}
```

...

```
void sleep(int milli) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milli);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make a function just to keep track of time so the code looks cleaner. Second, if you put a sleep inside the while so we dont occupy CPU time with busy wait. You can have more timed sections with more timer variables.

```
int countTime(int & time){
    now = getSystemTime();
    deltaTime = now - time;
    lastTime = now;
    return deltaTime
}

...

while(!isRunning){
    if(countTime(timer) >= 1000){
        //do something      
    }
    usleep(100000) // sleep so we don't occupy CPU
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it going to run forever? What is the context?

Try to make it like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { algorithm something here! }
            };      
final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Maybe it solve your problem!

If you have some question about the methods posted above, please check the oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html